# "About a hour ago" logic in PHP / SQL and how it affects performance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, benchmarking

Lately I have been facing websites with "X hours ago", "X days ago" features. (including stackoverflow)

Like,
Anil played a game around a hour ago.
Anil leveled up 2 days ago.
Anil posted this comment just now.

I know it can easily be done with a little function which calculates the old time to the current time, get difference in seconds (or miliseconds) and return a string value accordingly.

What I am trying to ask is;

1. How can it be done at most professional way? Calculating time difference with PHP or get it calculated on our SQL while querying?
2. Wouldn't it lower the performance? Imagine a page with 100 comments, the function will work 100 times, hence, the page will load slower.

Ps. I'm not looking for scripts.

Answer (score 5):

The usual approach is to use a normal SQL Query to gather the difference in time as an integer, and then convert it with PHP/Javascript.  In other words, nothing fancy.  Here is a PHP script used in most Twitter wrappers:

```
/**
* Formats a timestamp nicely with an adaptive "x units of time ago" message.
* Based on the original Twitter JavaScript badge. Only handles past dates.
* @return string Nicely-formatted message for the timestamp.
* @param $time Output of strtotime() on your choice of timestamp.
*/
function niceTime($time) {
  $delta = time() - $time;
  if ($delta < 60) {
    return 'less than a minute ago.';
  } else if ($delta < 120) {
    return 'about a minute ago.';
  } else if ($delta < (45 * 60)) {
    return floor($delta / 60) . ' minutes ago.';
  } else if ($delta < (90 * 60)) {
    return 'about an hour ago.';
  } else if ($delta < (24 * 60 * 60)) {
    return 'about ' . floor($delta / 3600) . ' hours ago.';
  } else if ($delta < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
    return '1 day ago.';
  } else {
    return floor($delta / 86400) . ' days ago.';
  }
}
?>
```

This is generally so fast that it should take little time more than usual.  If you have less than 300 or so calculations from this on a page you shouldn't see a performance drop.

Answer (score 3):

I think the performance implication is ignorable. Also you could do this on the client side, by sending normal timestamps to the client, e.g. for the web there is a jquery plugin that does this: [`jquery-timeago`](http://timeago.yarp.com/).

I would recommend to do this on the client side, because here the client can refresh it as wished (e.g. when the page stays open longer). Also the absolute data is available to the user, if needed.

Comment: If you're doing this on the client side, you must send the server's current timestamp to be used as reference. You cannot assume that people have set their clock properly.

Comment: @SalmanA: The timestamp should just be in some general timezone, e.g. GMT/UTC.

Comment: Still, you can not trust the client to have a valid time set. It can vary from 1 jan 1970 to several years into the future. If opting to calculate on client side you *should* remember to also send the timestamp from the server. Still I have to advice against doing this in javascript on the client side due to the performance of some javascript engines (Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8). Not to mention client without javascript. (Search engines, "dumb" phones, web tv, etc).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion goes to calculating differences with PHP.

What you could do is having a timestamp (consider a neutral timezone) in your db, and then make the query so that you dispay whatever fits your interval (IE timestamp - now() < N), where N is your time interval.

At that point, you use PHP to translate the event date to a difference from now (which could also be made dynamic client side - IE Javascript - for most recent entries, so to encompass seconds/minutes elapsed as ebay does with expiring actions).

The reason why I wouldn't put logic in the database is because I think that such data is application dependant, rather than db dependant - IE one day you might want to show time differences in another way, and db could not be the most versatile tool you have at hand - not necessarily because of performance (I think the impact can be neglegible anyways).

Answer (score 0):

It would almost certainly be best to do as a standalone function after the data have been fetched from the database.

It will, of course, incur a small overhead… But when that overhead is compared to the overhead of everything else you're doing to render the page, I expect it won't even be possible to measure (unless your algorithm is incredibly inefficient).

Additionally, since the database is often the bottleneck, not the app server's CPU, it's generally a good idea to do this kind of work on the app server instead of the database.

Answer (score 0):

100 times almost nothing is still almost nothing. Don't worry about it. One simple check as in:

```
if time > day
  write time.in_days + " days"
if time > hour
  write time.in_hours + " hours"
if time > minute
  write time.in_minutes + " minute"
if time > second
  write time.in_seconds + " seconds"
if time > millisecond
  write time.in_seconds + " milliseconds"
```

will only take you a few clock cycles. You will have 3 billion clock cycles at your disposal a second so a 100 calls to such a function would reach a millisecond of computational effort.

Answer (score 0):

In sql the calculation will cost you time to build because of the language.
the choice for me would be php or javascript. 
I've also heard of jquery solutions for this problem.
Javascript would press the calculation cost entirely to the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. get the timestamps from SQL,
2. use simple subtraction to get the difference in seconds
3. you can implement a simple Ordo log(n) function, rather than an Ordo n, to get the textual timelapse, like the following:

```
function niceTime($difference) {
  if ($difference > 86400)
    if ($difference > 2592000)
      if ($difference > 30758400) {
        $time = round($difference / 30758400);
        $unit = 'year';
      } else {
        $time = round($difference / 2592000);
        $unit = 'month';
      }
    else
      if ($difference > 604800) {
        $time = round($difference / 604800);
         $unit = 'week';
      } else {
        $time = round($difference / 86400);
        $unit = 'day';
      }
  else
    if ($difference > 900)
      if ($difference > 3600) {
        $time = round($difference / 3600);
        $unit = 'hour';
      } else {
        $time = round($difference / 900);
        $unit = 'quarter';
      }
    else
      if ($difference > 60) {
        $time = round($difference / 60);
        $unit = 'minute';
      } else {
        $time = round($difference);
        $unit = 'second';
      }
  return $time . ' ' . $unit . ($time != 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
}
```

The idea here is that you shouldn't iterate through eight steps to find out that a given difference indeed was the worst case scenario (over a year). Rather you split your options in half every time, and you will allways arive at the "correct" time in three comparisons.

In the worst case scenario where you have a page with 100.000 comments that are all two years old, this will reduce the number of comparisons from 800.000 to 300.000, which *will* be noticable. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have altered the code provided by sickle to add allowance for number of months, number of weeks, and years.

```
function agoTime($time) {
$delta = time() - $time;

if ($delta < 60) {
  return 'less than a minute ago.';
 } else if ($delta < 120) {
return 'about a minute ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (45 * 60)) {
return floor($delta / 60) . ' minutes ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (90 * 60)) {
return 'about an hour ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (24 * 60 * 60)) {
return 'about ' . floor($delta / 3600) . ' hours ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
return '1 day ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (11 * 24 * 60 * 60)) {
return 'about a week ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)) {
return 'about ' .floor($delta / 604800) . ' weeks ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (45 * 24 * 60 * 60)) {
return 'more than a month ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)) {
return 'about ' .floor($delta / 2592000) . ' months ago.';
 } else if ($delta < (550 * 24 * 60 * 60)) {
return 'more than a year ago.';
 } else {
return 'about ' .floor($delta / 31536000) . ' years ago.';
 }
```